# Как можно автоматизировать компиляцию .py в .exe?

Tags: python, компиляция, компилятор

Я знаю что можно легко компилировать .py в .exe через pyinstaller, но мне нужно автоматизировать компиляцию через скрипт, т.к. действия будут на сервере. Буду рад если поможете, только это осталось продумать, а так весь проект готов.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
FileList = ["2.py","3.py","hello.py"]
for i in range (len(FileList)):
    os.system("pyinstaller " + FileList[i])
```

так же через ***os*** можно получить список файлов в директории, и через проверку найти **.py** файлы
[документация](https://senkler.blogspot.com/2011/04/python.html)

Answer (score 0):

Тут можно и без python обычным bat-скриптом c содержимым:

```bsh
pyinstaller myfile.py
```

плюс необходимые Вам флаги по желанию.
Если есть какая-то логика сложнее компиляции заранее заданных файлов можно и python скрипты подключить. Но про это Вы не говорили ))